# Package not found error when running python code (submodule)

Tags: python, git-submodules

Project structure:

```
└── my_project
    ├── src
    │   ├── main.py
    │   └── submodule
    │       ├── src
    │       │   ├── myManager.py
    │       │   └── myClass.py
    │       └── ...
    ├── data
    └── ...
```

main.py:

```
from submodule.src.myManager import runManager
```

myManager.py:

```
from myClass import runClass
```

When I run main.py I have this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myClass'
```

I have to do:

```
try:
    from myClass import runClass
except ImportError:
    try:
        from .myClass import runClass
```

My submodule can also be launched on its own, and it only works with `from myClass import runClass` when I need to use `.myClass` when it's called by another project.

I tried to create `__init__.py` files but I did'nt manage to fix the error.

Comment: So why don't you just use `from .myClass import runClass`?

Comment: It doesn't work locally

Comment: What's the error when you use `from .myClass import runClass` locally?

Comment: I edited my post because I made a mistake

Comment: How are you running your submodule script? Have you tried running with `python -m <submodule>`?

Comment: It has its own main that uses myManager
Same behavior with -m